# Python error running Ansible via SSM against EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to run a fairly routing ansible playbook against ec2 instances in my AWS environment

```
---
- name: get python 
  hosts: myhost
  become: true

  vars:
    ansible_connection: aws_ssm
    ansible_aws_ssm_profile: myprofile
    ansible_aws_ssm_region: eu-west-1
    ansible_aws_ssm_bucket_name: "mybucketname"

  tasks:
    - name: run command
  command: pwd
```

I can see that the connection to the instance works, but I get the following error

```
fatal: [i-000011112222aaaa]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3.6"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "  File \"/home/ssm-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1641395807.063974-83634-44643497283265/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 1\r\r\n    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\r\n    ^\r\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\r",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 1,
            "warnings": [
                "Platform linux on host i-000011112222aaaa is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3.6, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.11/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information."
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

My ansible.cfg looks like this

```
[defaults]
enable_plugins = aws_ec2
host_key_checking = False
pipelining = True
ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python3.9
```

My ansible --version

```
ansible [core 2.11.6]
  config file = /Users/myuser/Repositories/myrepo/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/myuser/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

I can see in the ansible --version that python3.10 is being referenced, but I'm specifying 3.9 in my ansible_python_interpreter. Is there a reason on the host side this wouldn't work? Running the command directly on the host works without issue.

Comment: I think the error of interest doesn't have anything to do with Python versions. `"module_stdout": "  File \"/home/ssm-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1641395807.063974-83634-44643497283265/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 1\r\r\n    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\r\n    ^\r\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\r",` suggests that what is supposed to be a Python file instead has XML content, which isn't going to work. I'm not sure what could cause that behavior. Is the your first time using the `aws_ssm` connection module?

Comment: First time using the aws_ssm, I have just found this github issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49757 which mentions old versions of python but python2.x isn't installed on the machine (as far as I can tell) so not sure why i'd see the same error

Comment: The raw module works (presumably because it doesn't use python at all, where as other modules do) which would indicate it is a python issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the S3 bucket age.

1. During the run Ansible is trying to upload a Python file to S3.
2. It will then use a Signed-URL to download it from the EC2 instance, using a `curl` command against the S3 URL.
3. This will fail with a 307 HTTP status code, if the bucket is too new, since the `curl` URL is a global endpoint (see here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-http-307-response). It takes up to 24 hours for a new bucket to be propagated to all regions. Until then the attempt to download the file via `curl` may return an AWS error message that says something about a `TemporaryRedirect` (HTTP status code 307). That's why the Ansible run shows that the Python script apparently seems to contain XML content.
4. Check if the `ansible_aws_ssm_s3_addressing_style` parameter helps (it didn't in my case).

Possible solutions:

- wait 24 hours
- use an existing bucket that is older than 24 hours